# MVC3 - what is the best practice to validate the old data and new data when submitting a form

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using mvc3 for my web app.

When an user edit an existing form, make a few changes and save it.

what is the best practice to check which field in the form has been modified.

Regards,

Bubblegum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we're not talking data access - upon postback, compare it to your object in your database. This is somewhat of an open question because it depends what data access you are using and what models you are using. Entity framework Entities can track their modified state so you may be able to use

```
TryUpdateModel(yourInstanceLoadedFromYourDatabase)
```

and check the status of each field. That 'may' work, otherwise you are comparing each field. However why do you need to know specifically which field changed? Save the entire object back to the database (or simply merge with the values from the page using the same TryUpdateModel above)

Comment: Hi adam, thank you for the response. the reason why I asked is because if the fields have been updated i like to send an email to the admin. That's why I need to know which field has been modified.

Comment: I am using entity framework entities. I am using tryupdatemodel and i am not too sure how to check the status of each field. I will give it a go.

Comment: if they simply do a post (ie a SAVE) can't you assume then an email goes to the admin?  To detect an entity change, check out this method : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487246.aspx

"Any values that differ from the original values of the object are marked as modified."